# Hierarchial SQL Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question that I'm hoping you can help with. I've been trying to think of a way to display data in a manner that I'm looking for, without much success. Basically, the data is laid out as follows:

example of data:

```
UID | Name | Action | Parent_UID | Date         |  Category    |    Item
1   | John | Delete | (null)     | 10-DEC-2013  |    Cars      |    Cars
2   | John | Delete | 1          | 10-DEC-2013  |    Cars      |    Ford
3   | Mark | Add    | (null)     | 09-DEC-2013  |    Cars      |    Tesla
4   | Mark | Add    | 3          | 09-DEC-2013  |    Model     |    Model-S
5   | Mark | Add    | 4          | 09-DEC-2013  |   Inventory  |      5
```

The table contains parent records, as well as child records recording actions taken. The Parent records have a Parent_UID of null. There are many records in this table, and they aren't organized in any fashion by default. As you can see, the table can get very deep in terms of the layers of data.

What I would like to do is have the parent record first, followed by the child record.

I tried the following SQL in our Oracle database:

`select *
from  Table 
where Date > '09-DEC-2013'
and Name = 'John'
start with parent_uid is null
connect by parent_uid = uid;`

but it's taking forever to run and I'm not sure if the syntax is correct. Is there a better way to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: can you try `select * from Table where Date > '09-DEC-2013' and Name = 'John'order by parent_uid NULLS FIRST`? im not sure if this will resolve your performance problems

Comment: @deterministicfail Thanks for responding. I tried that but now the data is output with rows 1 and 3 from the example above first, then rows other rows. I'd like to see the output exactly as shown above

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in my post. I'd like to see the hierarchy. The data in the table isn't organized like it is in the example. It's all over the place, but I'd like to make the output similar to what's in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues:

- [`UID`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions223.htm#SQLRF06153) is a system function which uniquely identifies the session user - if you want to use it as a column name then you have to enclose it in double quotes `""`;
- `DATE` is a datatype and is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) - same as above, if you want to call a column `Date` then you need to wrap it in double quotes; and
- You need to connect the `parent_UID` to the `PRIOR "UID"`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc98a/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( "UID", Name, Action, Parent_UID, "Date", Category, Item ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'John', 'Delete', null, TO_DATE( '10-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY' ), 'Cars',      'Cars' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'John', 'Delete', 1,    TO_DATE( '10-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY' ), 'Cars',      'Ford' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Mark', 'Add',    null, TO_DATE( '09-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY' ), 'Cars',      'Tesla' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Mark', 'Add',    3,    TO_DATE( '09-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY' ), 'Model',     'Model-S' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Mark', 'Add',    4,    TO_DATE( '09-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY' ), 'Inventory', '5' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  "Date" >= TO_DATE( '09-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
AND    Name = 'John'
START WITH parent_UID IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR "UID" = parent_uid
ORDER SIBLINGS BY "UID"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc98a/9/0)**:

```
| UID | NAME | ACTION | PARENT_UID |                            DATE | CATEGORY | ITEM |
|-----|------|--------|------------|---------------------------------|----------|------|
|   1 | John | Delete |     (null) | December, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000 |     Cars | Cars |
|   2 | John | Delete |          1 | December, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000 |     Cars | Ford |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your connect by to be
CONNECT BY UID=PRIOR PARENT_UID

also check that indexes exist
For these fields.  One on uud+parent_uid
Should do the trick

Also to show hierarcy in your results you can use the
Level in your select list which will show the depth.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this as well but for some reason only rows where the parent_uid is null are being returned, no other rows.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `PRIOR` in your `CONNECT BY`.

```
SELECT *
-- don't name your table 'table'
FROM my_table  
-- don't name your column 'date'
-- also, use explicit conversion to a date
WHERE my_date > TO_DATE('09-12-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')  
  AND name = 'John'
START WITH parent_id IS NULL 
-- you want the parent id to be equal to the PRIOR id
-- also, don't name your column uid
CONNECT BY parent_id = PRIOR id;
```